# Get ClientID of a parameter on an ASP site

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a parameter for a method, that should be a string and I can't come up with how to <% *.ClientID %> to the thing as a variable like that. Since its a variable i can't wrap it in quotes since it will be taken literally and when I use the parameter like a variable (as you're supposed to) i get an ASP error saying it doesn't exist in the context (reading it literally).

Any Clues?

thanks guys

**Code Sample**

```
function next(currentControl, maxLength, nextControl) { 
   if (document.getElementById( currentControl<%=.ClientID %>).value.length >= maxLength) {
         document.getElementById( nextControl<%=.ClientID %>).focus(); 
   } 
   return false; 
}
```

**Call Sample**

```
wValCode.Attributes.Add("onkeyup","next('wValCode','3','wValThree')");
```

I know probably a primitive way of adding the attribute, but its how it was explained to me. I picked up ASP on the fly so don't be too hard on me ;)

**Static HTML**

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$wValThree" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_wValThree" style="width:33px;">
```

That is the only related reference I can find in the static html. Would it have been added in one of ASPs convoluted js files?

Comment: That was my latest attempt (Dumb but had to give it a shot)

Comment: Thanks JohnFx for doing that more correctly than I ;)

Comment: Where does the currentControl value passed into the function come from and what does it contain?

Comment: How do you call this method?  Can you give us a sample method call?  (You probably don't need to use ASP tags here..)

Comment: Well I do need access to the eventual input of everything so an ASP control seemed like the way to go. I'll post how added the attributes up top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you're binding the key events from code behind, you can just reference the client IDs at the time that you're doing the binding:

```
wValCode.Attributes.Add("onkeyup","next('" + wValCode.ClientID + "', '3', '" + wValThree.ClientID + "')");
```

Then, you already have the client IDs passed as parameters to the javascript function

```
function next(currentControl, maxLength, nextControl) { 
   if (document.getElementById(currentControl).value.length >= maxLength) {
         document.getElementById(nextControl).focus(); 
   } 
   return false; 
}
```

*An even better option* is to pass a reference to the calling object as the first parameter, using the [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) keyword:

```
//code behind
wValCode.Attributes.Add("onkeyup","next(this, '3', '" + wValThree.ClientID + "')");

//javascript function
function next(currentControl, maxLength, nextControl) { 
   if (currentControl.value.length >= maxLength) {
         document.getElementById(nextControl).focus(); 
   } 
   return false; 
}
```

Comment: This one made the most sense to me. But its not functioning yet... I'm thinkin another error possible? i put a breakpoint on firebug at the line where the function starts, got nothin, doesn't look as though its getting called or something

Comment: Next step to debugging is to view source in your browser and make sure that the attribute is rending on the control correctly.  Post up a sample of what is rendered for the control for us..

Comment: What's the best way to find out if the event is attached? find the tag for the element in the static html?

Comment: I got it!! I forgot for C# backends I had to add autoeventwireup true in the page directive. :) Thanks for the help - still would've been incorrect without your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the dot outside the ASP.NET tag:

```
currentControl.<%= ClientID %>
```

Comment: Well now I don't get a compilation error, but I don't believe its finding the control yet either since its still not acting as it did before I started using the Masterpage

Comment: I suspect this will give you the ClientID of the page, rather than the control you are looking for..